# Ti.Facebook closes and restarts application upon exiting

Tags: appcelerator, facebook-sdk-4.0, appcelerator-titanium

So we use Ti.Facebook, and follow the [steps](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.facebook/blob/master/ios/README.md) given to configure and initialize it.
Then we share a link/picture with it.

It works fine **BUT** when the sharing ends, and the FB app (which the module launches with FB.presentShareDialog(params)) closes it also closes the parent app which launched it, and subsequently the app restarts

I don't see any error messages on the ACS console, so I'm fairly sure its not just the app crashing due to some other reason.

Using Ti.Facebook 5.0.0 with Titanium SDK 5.1.1.GA, 5.1.2.GA

Has anyone managed to get it work properly with the new sdk/module?

Comment: NOTE: It's better to use these docs on the module instead of the repo readme: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.

Comment: Not sure who downvoted. I've made a ticket [TC-5838](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TC-5838) regarding this. Also note it only is an issue with iOS 8 + the rest of the environmen.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I posted it in the correct section, I noticed previous Ti.FB module tickets are under TIMOB, however I couldn't find this category when I created the ticket.

Comment: You cannot post in TIMOB directly. Appcelerator will triage TC and AC tickets and then move it to the correct project.